# Problem comparing French character Î

Tags: c#, string, compare, culture

When comparing "Île" and "Ile", C# does not consider these to be to be the same.

```
    string.Equals("Île", "Ile", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

For all other accented characters I have come across the comparison works fine.

Is there another comparison function I should use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are specifying to compare the strings using the Invariant culture's comparison rules. Evidently, in the invariant culture, the two strings are not considered equal.

You can compare them in a culture-specific manner using String.Compare and providing the culture for which you want to compare the strings:

```
if(String.Compare("Île", "Ile", new CultureInfo("fr-FR"), CompareOptions.None)==0)
```

Please note that in the french culture, those strings are also considered different. I included the example to show, that it is the culture that defines the sort rules. You might be able to find a culture that fits your requirements, or build a custom one with the needed compare rules, but that it probably not what you want.

For a good example of normalizing the string so there are no accents, [have a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net). After normalizing the string, you would be able to compare them and consider them equal. This would probably be the easiest way to implement your requirement.

## Edit

It is not just the I character that has this behaviour in the InvariantCulture, this statement also returns false:

```
String.Equals("Ilê", "Ile", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

The framework does the right thing - those characters are in fact different (has different meaning) in most cultures, and therefore they should not be considered the same.

Comment: Even if that worked, it strikes me as strange that the problem is particular to that one character.

Comment: @Bryan: `Î` is U+00CE, `I` is U+0049, they are totally different.