# odd results when comparing strings based on culture

Tags: c#, string, cultureinfo

is there a reason why :

string s1 = "aéa";
string s2 = "aea";

```
string result = s1.Equals(s2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
result = s1.Equals(s2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

result = false in all cases although my current culture is french.
I would expect one of the 2 lines should return true?

On the other hand, I get

```
int a = string.Compare(s1, s2, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace);
```

a = 0 meaning an equality.

This sounds paradoxal to me. Any explanation???

thx in advance.

Comment: You may refer to this url for some help.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876237/problem-comparing-french-character-%C3%8E

Comment: Your first two comparisons are ignoring case, while your 3rd comparison is ignoring [nonspacing combining characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which include the acute accent), so it seems logical that they would produce different results.  If you use `CompareOptions.IgnoreCase` I would guess that the results will match your first comparison.

Comment: @Mark 
The case is the same between  "aéa" and "aea".
So the comparison with CurrentCultureIgnoreCase should return true from my point of view?
I m looking for the different methods returning an equality for these strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first equality check, you are ignoring case with `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` in your current culture (fr). So, first check should be `false`.

In the second one, you are ignoring case in invariant culture with `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`. é is not equal to e in invariant culture. Those characters are in fact different (has different meaning) in most cultures. This check should be `false`.

In the last one, you are ignoring characters, such as diacritics, with `CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace`. The last one should be `true`.

Also, read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions).

Comment: OK, I see, I thought I oculd get an equality result for é and e based on StringComparison enum, it looks not.
I ll figure out a solution with CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace then.
Thank you for your time.